# Как перерисовать MediaView, после выбора нового медиафайла?

Tags: java, javafx

В программе предусмотрена возможность открывать другие медиафайлы, но после выбора следующего файла и его запуска появляется только звук, а видеокартинка не обновляется, как это реализовать в JavaFX?

```
public class MediaPlayerMain extends Application {

static Stage stage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {
        MediaPlayerMain.stage = stage;
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/application/MediaPlayerView.fxml");
        BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Media Player");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Stage getStage(){
    return stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}



public class MediaPlayerController implements Initializable {
@FXML
ToolBar toolBar;

@FXML
CheckBox checkBox;

@FXML
Slider slider;

@FXML
Button btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop, btnOpen;

@FXML
BorderPane borderPane;

private Media media;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaView mediaView;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {        
    borderPane.setCenter(createMediaView());
    toolBar = new ToolBar(btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop, btnOpen, slider, checkBox);
    borderPane.setBottom(toolBar);
    MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
    btnPlay.setOnAction(event);
    btnPause.setOnAction(event);
    btnStop.setOnAction(event);
    btnOpen.setOnAction(event);
}

public String getPath(){
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Media files","*.flv", "*.mp4", "*.mpeg"));
    File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.replace("\\", "/");
    return path;
}

public MediaView createMediaView(){
    media = new Media(new File(getPath()).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    return mediaView;   
}

public void fullScreen(ActionEvent event){
    if(checkBox.isSelected()){
        MediaPlayerMain.getStage().setFullScreen(true);
        System.out.println("Fullscreen true");
    }else{
        MediaPlayerMain.getStage().setFullScreen(false);
        System.out.println("Fullscreen false");
    }
}

class MyEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
        if (btn.equals(btnPlay)) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnPause)) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnStop)) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnOpen)){
            if(mediaPlayer.getStatus().equals(Status.PLAYING)){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                createMediaView().setMediaPlayer(new MediaPlayer(media));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(btn.getText());
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. никто не подсказал, нашел собственное решение. Код немного изменил, где-то добавил метод, где-то объединил. Класс MediaPlayerMain не поменялся, изменения были добавлены только в класс MediaPlayerController.

```
public class MediaPlayerController implements Initializable {
@FXML
ToolBar toolBar;

@FXML
CheckBox checkBox;

@FXML
Slider slider;

@FXML
Button btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop, btnOpen;

@FXML
BorderPane borderPane;

private Media media;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaView mediaView;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    borderPane.setCenter(createMediaView());
    createToolbar();
    MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
    btnPlay.setOnAction(event);
    btnPause.setOnAction(event);
    btnStop.setOnAction(event);
    btnOpen.setOnAction(event);
}

public void createToolbar() {
    toolBar = new ToolBar(btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop, btnOpen, slider, checkBox);
    borderPane.setBottom(toolBar);
}

public MediaView createMediaView() {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Media files", "*.flv", "*.mp4", "*.mpeg"));
    File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.replace("\\", "/");
    media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    return mediaView;
}

public void fullScreen(ActionEvent event) {
    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
        MediaPlayerMain.getStage().setFullScreen(true);
        System.out.println("Fullscreen true");
    } else {
        MediaPlayerMain.getStage().setFullScreen(false);
        System.out.println("Fullscreen false");
    }
}

class MyEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
        if (btn.equals(btnPlay)) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnPause)) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnStop)) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        } else if (btn.equals(btnOpen)) {
            if (mediaPlayer.getStatus().equals(Status.PLAYING)) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                borderPane.setCenter(createMediaView());
                createToolbar();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(btn.getText());
    }

}
}
```